# Why does window.innerWidth returns 477px even if the window has a smaller width?

Tags: javascript, mootools

When I resize the browser window to a lower width than 477px, `window.innerWidth` or `window.getSize().x` (using mootools) still returns `477px`.

Anyone ever had that problem? What's going on here?

The problem occurs in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: This happens in Firefox and also in Chrome (except that in chrome, the width is 532px instead of 477px)

Comment: I tried it and you are right. But the value varies with the website loaded in the window. I can see that the value of window.outerWidth is returning correct values regardless of the innerWidth.

Comment: i know that, but unfortunately, innerWidth and outWitdh doesn't work in IE !

Comment: workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/H4snF/1/ - `window.getCoordinates().width` returns fine.

Answer (score 4):

workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/H4snF/1 - `window.getCoordinates().width` returns fine.

Answer (score 0):

When the code gets called, is the window resized? It might be the case where the call to window.getSize().x gets called before you resize the window. Maybe you should attach the call to an anchor element on your page and only call it after the resize.

Comment: Well, the window is already resized when the code gets called, I always test via the firebug console, and even there, when I get to see the event windows properties, innerWidth is set to 477.

Comment: Did you refresh Firebugs DOM-Tab before watching the properties. DOM- TAB won't refresh automatic.

Comment: Yes, it refreshed with the browser, but i tried with an alert instead of a console.debug() and it still didn't worked out